# How can I display the short title of a (titlesec) part in the header?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titlesec, parts

I am writing a game rule-book in which titles of parts are displayed in two lines. The first line is the same as the short title (e.g. `\part[introduction]{introduction\\PARTIE PREMIÈRE}\label{\thepart}`) and I want to add only the upper line/short title to the header. I've managed to make it work with this code: `\fancyhead[CE]{\textsc{\nameref{\thepart}}}` but when I customize the `\part` with the titlesec package, it disappears from the header. No "??" or errors, just an empty header. (The odd pages' header displays the chapter's short name and works without any problems even though I've customized its style.)

Here's the whole code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,openright,14pt]{memoir}


\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}


\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\fontsize{21pt}{15pt}\scshape\centering}
    {#1}
    {1em}
    {}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\fontsize{18pt}{15pt}\scshape\centering}
    {#1\\\ligne}
    {1em}
    {}


\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{-40pt}


\newcommand{\chry}
    {\ding{97}}

\newcommand{\ligne}
    {\vspace{0.5cm}\fancybreak{
        \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[line width=0.45mm](0,0)--(3.75,0);\end{tikzpicture}
    }\vspace{0.5cm}}

\newcommand{\petiteligne}
    {\vspace{0.5cm}\fancybreak{
        \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[line width=0.45mm](0,0)--(1.875,0);\end{tikzpicture}
    }\vspace{0.5cm}}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}
    {0.45mm}


\fancyhf{}

\fancypagestyle{plain}
    {\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}
        {0pt}\fancyhf{}}

\begin{document}
    %Titre
        \begin{titlingpage}
            \includepdf{titre}
        \end{titlingpage}
    %/Titre

    \cleardoublepage

    %Préface
        \blindtext[5]
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textsc{préface}}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
        \pagenumbering{Roman}
    %/Préface

    \cleardoublepage

    %Contenu
        \fancyhead[CE]{\textsc{\nameref{\thepart}}}
        \fancyhead[CO]{\textsc{\nameref{\thepart.\thechapter}}}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \part[introduction]{introduction\\PARTIE PREMIÈRE}\label{\thepart}
            \chapter[univers]{univers\\CHAPITRE PREMIER}\label{\thepart.\thechapter}
                \blindtext[2]
                \petiteligne
                \blindtext[2]
    %/Contenu
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try loading titlesec with the `newparttoc` option?

Answer (score 1):

I found how thanks to [@Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer)! Here's the code without labels:

```
\newcommand*\parttitle{}
\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand*{\part}[2][]{%
   \ifx\\#1\\% optional argument not present?
      \origpart{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#2}%
   \else
      \origpart[#1]{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#1}%
   \fi
}
```